# Rotate image fill inside a shape

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, images, rotate

I have been struggling with this for quite a while now...is there a way to rotate an image fill inside a shape using VBA?

All the posts I have seen online only over solutions as to how to rotate the shape without rotating the fill but I want it the other way around. Keeping the shape as it is and only rotating the image fill...

Comment: You'd better provide more information, you can provide the article here.

Comment: My guess is you have to rotate the image outside of excel, then bring it back as a fill image...

Comment: @Lee there is no more information. There are absolutely no articles on how to do that

Comment: @gns100 I find it really hard to believe there is no other way. It is troublesome rotating every image outside of excel and defies my purpose for a fluid user experience...